# Split large XML into small files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I have a large XML similar to

```
<root>
  ...
  ...
  <item>
    <more>
      <nested>
        <tags>
          <detail>
          ...
          </detail>
          <detail>
          ...
          </detail>
          <detail>
          ...
          </detail>
          ...
        </tags>
      </nested>
    </more>
  </item>
  <item>
  </item>
  ...
</root>
```

This is a fairly large file and I need to split this file into multiple files with one or more `<detail>` elements per file with `<item>` as the root element in the split files and carrying all child elements of `<item>` element. For example,

file-1.xml:

```
<item>
  <more>
    <nested>
      <tags>
        <detail>
        ...
        </detail>
        <detail>
          ...
        </detail>
        </tags>
      </nested>
    </more>
</item>
```

file-2.xml:

```
<item>
  <more>
    <nested>
      <tags>
        <detail>
        ...
        </detail>
        <detail>
          ...
        </detail>
        </tags>
      </nested>
    </more>
</item>
```

In the example above, I am splitting with two `<detail>` elements per file but I would like to configure the number of `<detail>` elements per file in xslt. Is this something that can be accomplished with XSLT 2.0? I am using Java and Saxon. Thank you.

A more complete xml input file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<payment>
  <item>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <id>2367</id>
    <type_a>
      <tag1></tag1>
      <tag2></tag2>
      <header>
        <ticket_number>009412</ticket_number>
        <total_amount>108479.53</total_amount>
        <number>1</number>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-1</qref>
          <aref>aref-1</aref>
          <field>
            <name>Request ID</name>
            <value>10267643280</value>
          </field>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-2</qref>
          <aref>aref-2</aref>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-3</qref>
          <aref>aref-3</aref>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-4</qref>
          <aref>aref-4</aref>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-5</qref>
          <aref>aref-5</aref>
        </detail>
      </header>
    </type_a>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Name2</name>
    <id>3412</id>
    <type_a>
      <header>
        <type>card</type>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-a-2-1</qref>
          <aref>aref-a-2-1</aref>
        </detail>
      </header>
    </type_a>
    <type_b>
      <header>
        <type>card</type>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-2-1</qref>
          <aref>aref-2-1</aref>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-2-2</qref>
          <aref>aref-2-2</aref>
        </detail>
        <detail>
          <qref>qref-2-3</qref>
          <aref>aref-2-3</aref>
        </detail>
      </header>
    </type_b>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Name2</name>
    <id>3412</id>
  </item>
  <footer>
    <name>name</name>
    <date>2023-05-22T10:20:59</date>
  </footer>
</payment>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible using the `xsl:result-document` instruction. Please provide a clearer example (with some data, so that we can see what goes where) and explain what exactly do you mean by "configure the number of <detail> elements per file".

Comment: Added a more complete sample. I am looking to configure the number of ```<detail>``` elements per file through an XSLT param so I can change it dynamically.

Comment: It is still not clear. You have 2 (or more) items, each with several details.  Should each item's details be handled separately? And what about the other nodes, e.g. items that do not have any details and the footer??

Comment: footer should be ignored as it is outside item element. I need ```<item>``` as the root element in the split files and each split files should have, say, 2 ```<detail>``` elements. So, in the example above, there should be a total of 5 split files; 3 from the first item and two from the second item. The item without detail should not generate any file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="details-per-file" as="xs:integer" select="2"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="subtree-root" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select=".//detail" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $details-per-file">
      <xsl:variable name="subtree-nodes" select="$subtree-root/descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()/(ancestor::node(), ., descendant::node())"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="item-{generate-id()}-{position()}.xml" indent="yes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::item" mode="subtree">
          <xsl:with-param name="subtree" tunnel="yes" select="$subtree-nodes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>        
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="subtree" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="subtree">
    <xsl:param name="subtree" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test=". intersect $subtree">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have used XSLT 3 as Saxon since 9.8 and 2017 supports that version anyway, as do other Saxon releases.

But if you really use a version of Saxon that old that it only supports XSLT 2.0 then remove the `xsl:mode` declarations and use e.g.

```
<!--      
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>
-->

<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<!--
<xsl:mode name="subtree" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
-->

<xsl:tempate mode="subtree" match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()" mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

After you have more thoroughly explained your input and wanted output and based on your comments it looks like the following should on the one hand ensure only two `detail`s per `item` end up in a result file but other data is copied to each result file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:param name="details-per-file" as="xs:integer" select="2"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="subtree-root" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select=".//detail" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $details-per-file">
      <xsl:variable name="subtree-nodes" select="$subtree-root/descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()/(ancestor::node(), ., descendant::node())"/>
      <xsl:variable name="subtree-nodes" select="$subtree-nodes, $subtree-root/descendant-or-self::node()[not(self::detail)][some $detail in current-group() satisfies . &lt;&lt; $detail]"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="item-{generate-id()}-{position()}.xml" indent="yes">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::item" mode="subtree">
          <xsl:with-param name="subtree" tunnel="yes" select="$subtree-nodes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>        
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode name="subtree" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="node()" mode="subtree">
    <xsl:param name="subtree" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:if test=". intersect $subtree">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As for the comment about what the selection of `subtree-nodes` does, it was an attempt to select all nodes to be part of a result document tree; initially I didn't expect that to include or duplicate data before the `detail`s but based on your comments and added sample I think I needed to adjust/add to those nodes so that is why the second sample adds the descendants in `item` that are not `detail`s but precede some item in the current group.

Comment: Thank you Martin, this works great. However some tags under ```<item>``` are not copied. In my example above, ```<more><nested><tags>``` has a combination of child and sibling nodes and it is copying only child nodes. I can attach a sample

Comment: If you can provide some insight into what this selection does - ```<xsl:variable name="subtree-nodes" select="$subtree-root/descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()/(ancestor::node(), ., descendant::node())"/>```. Is descendent-or-self selecting only descendents and not each descendent's children?

Comment: @ashburnite, I have edited the answer and added a second, improved sample that might do the "capture" of any nodes besides the `detail`s in the various result documents; I have also added a paragraph trying to explain what the variable is good for; it essentially tries to compute the nodes forming a result tree once to then easily be able to have a mode making sure nothing but the computed nodes end up in a result tree.

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks Martin. In the sample where both type_a and type_b tags are within the same item tag, your xslt is splitting the file correctly, however, an empty, type_a tag is added to the last split file but that is not a big deal. Let me do some more testing and will accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="groupSize" select="2"/>

<xsl:template match="/payment">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item[descendant::detail]" mode="split"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="split">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="id" />
    <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::detail" group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $groupSize">
        <xsl:result-document href="{$id}_{position()}.xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::item"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>   
</xsl:template>
    
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="header">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* except detail | current-group()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Like Michael Kay's answer, this is based on the fact that the scope of `current-group()` extends to applied templates.

Comment: works flawlessly for the sample provided above. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have a template just for header element and not for say, type_a? Is it not possible to copy *everything* under ```<item>``` except ```<detail>```?

Comment: It is because header is the parent of detail. All other elements are handled by the identity transform template. We need to make an exception for header, otherwise it will apply templates to ALL its child detail, not just the current group.

Comment: Michael, I have run into an issue. I have updated the sample xml and in the bottom item element, I have both type_a and type_b elements. This causes the fourth split file to have 4 detail records

Comment: I don't even know what the rules are for such arrangement.

Comment: Thanks Michael and appreciate the time you spent on my problems. Although you answered my original ask, Martin has given a working solution for the enhanced problem

Comment: You shouldn't make such radical changes to the question after it has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach might be

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:variable name="item" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select=".//detail" 
       group-adjacent="(position() - 1) idiv $details-per-file">
    <xsl:result-document href="{position()}.xml">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$item" mode="fragment"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:mode name="fragment" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="*/detail" mode="fragment">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Couple of issues. The file names need more than position() because when the second ```<item>``` is parsed, 1.xml is written again and I get a Saxon error. Each split file has duplicate ```<detail>``` elements. For example, 1.xml has two ```<detail>``` elements replicated 5 times

Comment: OK, I missed some details of your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with powershell and xml linq

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$filename = "c:\temp\test"

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($filename + '.xml')
$root = $doc.Root

$items = @($doc.Descendants('item'))

for($i = 1; $i -le $items.Length; $i++)
{
   $root.RemoveAll()
   $root.Add($items[$i - 1])
   $doc.Save($filename + $i + '.xml')
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for Java/Saxon solution and in the above code, looks like you are copying the entire ```<item>``` into the split file instead of copying pre-configured number of ```<detail>``` elements

Comment: You missed the RemoveAll()