# Splitting XML into multiple files using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

Using XSLT 2.0 I try to split xml and separate all item groups.

Original xml:

```
<Root Name="Root1">
  <Info Name="Info1" />
  <Group id="1">
    <Client Code="1">
      <ItemGroup Name="Group1"><Data/></ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup Name="Group2"><Data/></ItemGroup>
    </Client>
    <Client Code="2">
      <ItemGroup Name="Group3"><Data/></ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup Name="Group4"><Data/></ItemGroup>
    </Client>
  </Group>
</Root>
```

Desired output, part1:

```
<Root Name="Root1">
  <Info Name="Info1" />
  <Group id="1">
    <Client Code="1">
      <ItemGroup Name="Group1"><Data/></ItemGroup>
    </Client>
  </Group>
</Root>
```

Desired output, part2:

```
<Root Name="Root1">
  <Info Name="Info1" />
  <Group id="1">
    <Client Code="1">
      <ItemGroup Name="Group2"><Data/></ItemGroup>
    </Client>
  </Group>
</Root>
enter code here
```

Desired output, part3:

```
<Root Name="Root1">
  <Info Name="Info1" />
  <Group id="1">
    <Client Code="2">
      <ItemGroup Name="Group3"><Data/></ItemGroup>
    </Client>
  </Group>
</Root>
```

Desired output, part4:

```
<Root Name="Root1">
  <Info Name="Info1" />
  <Group id="1">
    <Client Code="2">
      <ItemGroup Name="Group4"><Data/></ItemGroup>
    </Client>
  </Group>
</Root>
```

I managed to split it, but having difficulties to add the parent nodes.

My best attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/Root/Group/Client">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="ItemGroup" group-by="@Name">
        <xsl:result-document href="ItemGroup_{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is there any data to group in that sample input? Do you want several result files? Then spell them out or at least make it clear with several result samples which result you want.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76994976/3016153.

Comment: Added some output files to make things clear. In order to use xsl:result-document the min xslt-standard is 2.0. I'm using XMLSpy for transforming, I believe it's using Altova RaptorXML proceessor v. 2.0 or 3.0.

Comment: Why is `<ItemGroup Name="Group4">` excluded from the output?

Comment: Did you see and try to implement the suggestions on a similar question with answers that Michael already linked to (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76994976/3016153)?

Comment: Note that no actual grouping is taking place in your example. And it's not clear what is the expected result in case the same `ItemGroup` appears under more than one `Client`.

Comment: Fixed group4, currently experimenting with the answer in the shared link, it might be it.
If ItemGroup appears under more than one Client it should not merge it, but I believe it's a very rare case. ItemGroup id's might be the same, but not it's content.

Comment: If there is the slightest chance that two or more Clients have an ItemGroup with the same Name, then you should be grouping by ItemGroup's Name **and** the parent Client's Code (assuming that's unique). P.S. See here how to identify your processor and the supported XSLT version:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153

Comment: Vendor: Altova GmbH
Version: 2.0
After hours of trying, unfortunately, Michael link didn't help. I think it's faster to parse and assemble xml by high-level programming language. The xslt learning curve is just much more resource-consuming for the moment. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Root/Group/Client/ItemGroup" group-by="@Name">
      <xsl:result-document href="ItemGroup_{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="Group | Client | ItemGroup">
    <xsl:if test=". intersect current-group()/ancestor-or-self::*">
      <xsl:next-match/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online example](https://witty-dune-0fb497610.3.azurestaticapps.net/?code=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%223.0%22%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22Root%2FGroup%2FClient%2FItemGroup%22%20group-by%3D%22%40Name%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aresult-document%20href%3D%22ItemGroup_%7Bcurrent-grouping-key%28%29%7D.xml%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%2F*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aresult-document%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22Group%20%7C%20Client%20%7C%20ItemGroup%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22.%20intersect%20current-group%28%29%2Fancestor-or-self%3A%3A*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3CRoot%20Name%3D%22Root1%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CInfo%20Name%3D%22Info1%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CGroup%20id%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CClient%20Code%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItemGroup%20Name%3D%22Group1%22%3E%3CData%2F%3E%3C%2FItemGroup%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItemGroup%20Name%3D%22Group2%22%3E%3CData%2F%3E%3C%2FItemGroup%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FClient%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CClient%20Code%3D%222%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItemGroup%20Name%3D%22Group3%22%3E%3CData%2F%3E%3C%2FItemGroup%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CItemGroup%20Name%3D%22Group4%22%3E%3CData%2F%3E%3C%2FItemGroup%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FClient%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2FGroup%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FRoot%3E&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML).

Comment: I will mark this answer as correct, since Saxon 11 generate perfect result. However Altova XSLT processor generate 4 empty files wthout any errors, might be related to xslt 3.0 version. Lets leave it as it is, thanks for your time